# How to auto generate uuid in cassandra CQL 3 command line

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

Just learning cassandra, is there a way to insert a UUID using CQL, ie

```
create table stuff (uid uuid primary key, name varchar);
insert into stuff (name) values('my name'); // fails
insert into stuff (uid, name) values(1, 'my name'); // fails
```

Can you do something like

```
insert into stuff (uid, name) values(nextuid(), 'my name');
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can with time uuids (type 1 UUID) using the [now()](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html) function e.g.

```
insert into stuff (uid, name) values(now(), 'my name');
```

Works with uid or timeuuid.  It generates a "guaranteed unique" UID value, which also contains the timestamp so is sortable by time.

There isn't such a function for type 4 UUIDs though.

---

**UPDATE:** This note pertains to older versions of Cassandra. For newer versions, see below.

Comment: Is there any disadvantage to using timeuuid vs uuid?

Comment: The main disadvantage is it leaks the MAC address of the creator and the time.  But the advantages are its uniqueness is deterministic and you can sort events by time.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your detailed reply!

Comment: Actually, a TimeUUID *is* a UUID. Just like a Braeburn apple *is* an apple. Read the Cassandra doc and my longer answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945677/cassandra-uuid-vs-timeuuid-benefits-vs-disadvantages/17946236#17946236

Comment: this is not the best answer, check out the one from Zhivko

Comment: @Richard it seems to me that it is generated on the coordinator node so doesn't leak the local MAC address?  Anyway this way is sortable by time, not sure why this way would be disdained...

Answer (score 93):

As of [Cassandra 2.0.7](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6473) you can just use uuid(), which generates a random type 4 UUID:

```
INSERT INTO users(uid, name) VALUES(uuid(), 'my name');
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer for newer versions of cassandra!

Comment: @gotch4 yes, they are unique.  For all practical purposes.

Comment: @TorstenBronger would you be able to help me understand how uuid() is unique for a table?

Comment: “UUID” stands for “universally unique identifier”. It is supposed to be unique even beyond the table.  Its Wikipedia article has the details.

Answer (score 21):

Actually there is a way to do that using the blob conversion functions - `blobAsType()` and `typeAsBlob()`. In your case this should be:

```
insert into stuff (uid, name) values(blobAsUuid(timeuuidAsBlob(now())), 'my name');
```

This converts `timeuuid` to `blob` and from the `blob` converts it to `uuid`.

Comment: This actually answers the question. Nice.

Comment: Also believe this is the correct answer. The thing is we don't need to change the type from uuid to timeuuid

Answer (score 14):

A UUID is a Universally Unique ID used to avoid collisions.

Cassandra 2.0.7 and later versions include the `uuid()` function that takes no parameters and generates a Type 4 UUID for use in `INSERT` or `SET` statements.

You can also use a `timeuuid` type with a function like `now()`. They generate a Type 1 UUID.

The difference between Type 1 and Type 4 UUIDs is that a Type 1 UUID is generated using a timestamp and a Type 4 is generated using random numbers.

If you want to use a `timeuuid` as a `uuid` use something like `blobAsUuid(timeuuidAsBlob(now()))`, since the value returned by `now()` is guaranteed to be unique.

References:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/uuid_type_r.html

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/blob_r.html