# How do you insert custom timeuuid's to cassandra without the now() function?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0

I was trying to insert a specific timeuuid to cassandra and the only way I managed to insert one was using the now() function, because I assume, the now function knows what format the database likes it.

How do I create cqlsh command for this?

Currently I have this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (tid) VALUES ( now() )
```

But I would like to be able to have 100% control of what date I insert for testing purposes when I am debugging my node.js or whatever program interfacing cassandra.

It would be nice to have something like:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (tid) VALUES ( 12/OCTOBER/2014 )
```

without it crashing

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `minTimeuuid` and `maxTimeuuid` functions. It's a bad idea to insert their result, but for testing purposes it can be OK.

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#timeuuidFun

Comment: doing minTimeuuid('2014-10-12') worked for me in cqlsh during an insert query to the cassandra database. Apparently, single vs double quotes might make a difference (did for me). Careful with that.

Comment: Could we possibly have a little more detail at to why it is a "bad idea" except in testing?

Comment: @JGleason Because we will have the same id from call `minTimeuuid` or `maxTimeuuid` with the same data. It's not true UUID, it's just top and bottom border values.

Answer (score 3):

timeuuid's are a complex format.  Valid values are described [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/valid_literal_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_rgn_xy5_yj).

```
timeuuid

Uses the time in 100 nanosecond intervals since 00:00:00.00 UTC (60 bits), a 
clock sequence number for prevention of duplicates (14 bits), plus the IEEE 801 MAC
address (48 bits) to generate a unique identifier. For example: 
d2177dd0-eaa2-11de-a572-001b779c76e3
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945677/cassandra-uuid-vs-timeuuid-benefits-and-disadvantages) has a good discussion of `timeuuid`.  I do not know what order these bits appear in, but if it is from left to right you could concat:

**Time** (first 15 digits = 60 bits):
00000000-0000-000

**Sequence** (next 3 digits = 12 bits, ignores last 2 bits of sequence):
0-00

**Last 2 bits sequence + MAC**:
000-000000000000

Then increment the **Time** or the **Sequence** as needed for entries.  But it would probably be a lot easier to just work with timestamps.

If you want to do this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (tid) VALUES ( "2014-10-12" )
```

you need to use the `timestamp` type.

Comment: sorry to be snarky.  datastax is a great place to go for cassandra doc.

Comment: don't worry, you don't have to apologize. I was just so surprised/annoyed/shocked that the source I was looking at didn't have a clear explanation of the syntax. But reckoned that if I had the problem, probably someone else would have it in the future and it wouldn't hurt to help future people. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: I am not sure why its not working do you have an idea?, INSERT INTO commits (hash, keyframe, tid) VALUES (0x000000001bfdeb0a304b372dd8dda123b3fd1a00, true, "2012-01-01");

Comment: Bad Request: line 1:100 no viable alternative at input '2012-01-01'

Comment: huh.  what does `describe table commits` return?

Comment: CREATE TABLE commits (
  hash blob,
  keyframe boolean,
  tid timeuuid,
  PRIMARY KEY (hash)
)

Comment: WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};

Comment: my bad, i was writing about timestamp type.  i have updated my answer

Comment: so what does d2177dd0-eaa2-11de-a572-001b779c76e3 stand for?

Comment: updated with an explanation and how you could do it.  i have not done this before but it should work

Answer (score 3):

I you have 2 options:

1. use one of the `minTimeuuid` or `maxTimeuuid` described [here](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#timeuuidFun)
2. Implement a Timeuuid value in Node.js by using the details in [UUIDGen](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/UUIDGen.java)

I'd say the first approach would be easier for testing purposes.

Comment: Hi @AlexPopescu, Is there an updated documentation for this? `minTimeuuid` and `maxTimeuuid` no longer accept serialized dates as arguments from what I am able to tell.

Comment: @flavian: no longer as in what Cassandra version, what cqlsh, etc. etc.

Comment: Cassandra 2.2.0. I created a full spec issue here: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/projects/JAVA/issues/JAVA-1084?filter=allopenissues