# what is the difference between Cassandra UUID vs TimeUUID

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax, uuid, nosql

Can you please help me understand the difference between Cassandra UUID vs TimeUUID data type values ?

Many Thanks

Comment: maybe you can find it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945677/cassandra-uuid-vs-timeuuid-benefits-and-disadvantages

Comment: thank you. It answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

The [Cassandra Docs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/uuid_type_r.html) have an explanation of the difference between the two types.

The key difference is,

> A value of the timeuuid type is a Type 1 UUID. A type 1 UUID includes the time of its generation and are sorted by timestamp...

It is easy to think of a UUID as a randomly generated unique key and a TIMEUUID as a randomly generated unique key with a timestamp embedded within making sorting possible.

Answer (score 0):

The timeuuid cassandra type is a type 1 uuid, which is composed of a date-time, MAC address, and sequence number. If generated from the same location, they will be monotonically increasing, hence somewhat compressible when you compress many.

The uuid cassandra type is a type 4 uuid, which is just a huge random number. It is not monotonic or compressible.

Everything is detailed there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier