# Bad Request: Invalid STRING constant ... of type timeuuid

Tags: cassandra

When I do `select * from "TableToFetch" where column1='2js88saa-33oo-pzl7-b517-8584j2kf8wdd';` I get this error:

> Bad Request: Invalid STRING constant
>   (2js88saa-33oo-pzl7-b517-8584j2kf8wdd) for column1 of type timeuuid

These didn't help:

`select * from "TableToFetch" where column1="2js88saa-33oo-pzl7-b517-8584j2kf8wdd";` returns

> Bad Request: line 1:52 no viable alternative at input '2js88saa-33oo-pzl7-b517-8584j2kf8wdd'

`select * from "TableToFetch" where column1=2js88saa-33oo-pzl7-b517-8584j2kf8wdd;` returns

> Bad Request: TimeUUID supports only version 1 UUIDs

What do I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first two errors is caused by the fact that you wrap your uuid with quotes: the first one gets interpreted as string, the second one does not get recognized as any type.

*UUID and TimeUUID can/should be used in queries without any quotes.*

The third error message is regarding the TimeUUID type, Apache Cassandra uses UUID of type 1, so it seems that `2js88saa-33oo-pzl7-b517-8584j2kf8wdd` is probably not a valid type 1 UUID. Your query seems to be ok, to me.

Also I am not sure how do you execute your query (cql or via driver) or what version of Cassandra do you use, but this answer might be relevant for you, too:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17946236/9020666