# Insert UUID data type values in Cassandra Database Using Apache Metamodel

Tags: jdbc, cassandra, apache-metamodel

I want to insert UUID type values in Cassandra database using Apache Metamodel. For text data type I am using like

> .values("ColName", value)

How can I insert UUID type values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055630/inserting-a-hard-coded-uuid-via-cqlsh-cassandra) SO question says it should look something like

> `.values(colName, 77820258-ef49-4e61-8a74-debbdd5993ea)`

if you have a hardcoded UUID. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945341/how-to-auto-generate-uuid-in-cassandra-cql-3-command-line) gives various ways you can auto-generate a UUID.

Comment: thank you for reply, I got my point. Instead of value we can also use UUIDs.random(), It'll generate uuid randomly.